# Families of bounded (or closed) subsets of $\mathbb{R}^1$ with empty intersection, but having the finite intersection property

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

> **2.36 Theorem.** If $\{K_{\alpha}\}$ is a collection of compact subsets of a metric space $X$ such that the intersection of every finite subcollection of $\{K_{\alpha}\}$ is nonempty, then $\bigcap K_{\alpha}$ is nonempty.
>
> **Corollary.** If $\{K_n\}$ is a sequence of nonempty compact sets such that $K_n\supset K_{n+1}$ then $\cap_{1}^{\infty}K_n$ is not empty.
>
> Show that Theorem 2.36 and its Corollary become false (in $\mathbb{R}^1,$ for example) if the word "compact" is replaced by "closed" or by "bounded".

**"Bounded" example:** Let $E_n=(-1/n,0)\cup(0,1/n)$ for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$. It is clear that $E_n$ are bounded. Any finite intersection of $\{E_n\}$ is nonempty but $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n=\varnothing$.

**"Closed" example:** Let $F=\{0\}\cup \{1/n:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$. It is clear that $F$ is bounded and closed set. Let $F_0=F\backslash\{0\},$ $F_1=F_0\backslash\{1\}$, $F_2=F_1\backslash\{1/2\}$,.., $F_n=F_{n-1}\backslash\{1/n\}$. It is obvious that any finite intersection of $\{F_n\}$ is nonempty, but $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}F_n=\varnothing$.

Comment: $F_k$ is not closed for any $k\in \mathbb{N}$. Since $F$ is compact, you can't have a counterexample in that, because closed subsets of compact sets are compact. For the "closed counterexample", you **need** unbounded sets if you look at subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Yeah! You are right. I forgot about this condition. I need to correct the countre-example.

Comment: There are examples of families of closed sets with the finite intersection property such that the intersection of the whole family is empty. Just, if you look at subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, these closed sets necessarily must be unbounded, for a closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact. And if any compact set is in the family, the finite intersection property then implies a nonempty intersection of the whole family.

Comment: But I think that the couterexample with segment unsuitable.

Comment: Consider the sets $[n,\infty)$.

Comment: Dear David Mitra. I am also considered such example. But $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}[n,\infty)=\infty$ or not?

Comment: @Pacman No. None of the sets contains $\infty$, so the intersection is empty.

Comment: Why? After all $\infty$ belongs to all $[n, \infty)$

Comment: $\infty$ is a formal symbol that is not a member of the real numbers

Comment: I.e, $[n,\infty)$ is shorthand notation for $\{x:x\in \mathbb R \text { and } x \ge n\}$

Comment: Ok! Thank you very much. It was really informative.

Comment: What is the source for the Theorem, Corollary and problem? Maybe add that information to your question.

Comment: w. rudin principles of mathematical analysis